# Java "double cannot be dereferenced" error - calling method on double data type

Tags: java, methods, double, wrapper

I'm trying to use the following method for conversion between temperature scales in Java. Problem is when I call the method I get a `"double cannot be dereferenced"` error.

I understand that the reason is that methods cannot be called on primitive data types, and I think the solution is to use a wrapper but I'm not sure what that code would look like (my initial attempts at using Double wrapper all produced errors).

```
public double celsius(double f) {        
    return (f - 32.0)/1.8; 
}

public double fahrenheit(double c) {        
    return c * 1.8 + 32.0;
}

public void doConversion() {
    double tempC = 0.0;
    double tempF = tempC.fahrenheit; // double cannot be dereferenced error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the methods defined in you class. While doing conversion, you just have to call those methods like below:

```
public void doConversion() {
    double tempC = 0.0;
    double tempF = fahrenheit(tempC);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
double tempF = tempC.fahrenheit;
```

use

```
double tempF = fahrenheit(tempC);
```

Comment: Oops, typo.  `=` and `-` are next to each other. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Helpful. I wasn't aware of calling a method that way (new to Java).

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
public class temperature{
    public double T; //in C

    public temperature(double T){
        this.T = T;
    }

    public double getC(){
        return T;
    }

    public double getF(){
        return T * 1.8 + 32.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your code to work, you need to:

```
public void doConversion() {
    double tempC = 0.0;
    double tempF = fahrenheit(tempC);  // call your function
}
```

The reason `double tempF = tempC.fahrenheit;` is a problem is that the `.` (i.e. dot) is meant to allow classes and objects to access their member fields and methods.

A variable of type `double` is a *primitive* type; it's not a class or an object, so the dot operator cannot be used with them.

The wording in the messaging is because classes and their instances (i.e. objects) are always *references*. In other words, if you do something like:

```
List<DisplayMode> displayModes = new ArrayList<>();
```

the variable `displayModes` holds a reference (i.e. points to) the list, but is not the list itself. You can then do something like `displayModes.add(new DisplayMode(...));`

Notice you need to use the `new` operator with classes, but not with primitives.

On the other hand, if you write:

```
int x = 5;
```

the variable `x` is the value itself.

If you really want to use the dot operator, then consider something like:

```
Temperature temp = new Celsius(0.0);
System.out.println(temp.toFahrenheit().toString());
```

Assuming that you have an *interface* called `Temperature` with at least a method called `toFahrenheit()` and concrete classes `Celsius` and `Fahrenheit` *implementing* said interface.

```
public interface Temperature {
    Temperature toFahrenheiht();
}

public class Celsius implements Temperature {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Helpful and thorough answer.

Comment: @Craig90: We generally say thank you around here by up-voting answers :)

Comment: I did upvote your answer, but because I am new to Stack Overflow I don't have enough reputation for my upvote to register. The upvote will appear once I reach 15 reputation. Because the upvote won't appear immediately, I wrote a thank you comment.